# How do I manipulate the props in a Astro component using the <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I am a new Astro user and I come from vanilla HTML and JS. I'm trying to make a Wikipedia webscraper in Astro. I use a component that uses the 'query' prop to fetch data from Wikipedia.

`Index.astro`

```
---
import Wiki from "../components/Wiki.astro";
---

<title>Hello World</title>
<body class="m-5">
  <h1 class="text-3xl text-accent">Enter a query to search from:</h1>
  <form id="search-form">
    <input
      id="query"
      type="text"
      name="query"
      class="rounded border-b-[3px] border shadow-md px-3 py-2 w-96 mt-6 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-accent focus:ring-opacity-30 text-text"
    />
    <button id="form" class="rounded border-2 px-3 py-2">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <br />
  <Wiki query="George Washington" />
</body>
```

`../components/Wiki.astro`

```
---
import { load } from "cheerio";
const { query } = Astro.props;

const data = { heading: "", paragraphs: "" };

const response = await fetch(`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${query}`);
const html = await response.text();
const $ = load(html);

// Extract relevant information using Cheerio selectors
const title = $("h1#firstHeading").text();
const content = $("p").text();
data.heading += title;
data.paragraphs += content;
---

<div class="border">
  <h1>
    {data.heading}
  </h1>
  <p>
    {data.paragraphs}
  </p>
</div>
```

The Wiki component works as expected, but how do I manipulate the prop passed to the component?

I tried using document.createElement to create a Astro element, but it didn't register as one. I'm guessing its because of the inner compiling of Astro or something. I'm pretty sure the way I'm approaching this might be wrong, so please feel free to tell me a different way to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Astro components are rendered to plain HTML and so not dynamic in the browser.

In your example, the following happens:

1. Your index page renders including the `<Wiki />` component, passing in a `query` value.
2. Your `<Wiki />` component renders, sees the value of `query`, fetches the required data, and outputs the resulting HTML.
3. A user loads your page, the page contains *just* the plain HTML you generated, i.e. for your `<Wiki />` component, perhaps something like:

   ```html
   <div class="border">
     <h1>George Washington</h1>
     <p>George Washington (February 22, 1732 – December 14, 1799) was...</p>
   </div>
   ```

   No JavaScript is sent, all the logic in the `---` block is discarded, so there’s no logic to re-render or use the component on the client-side. (This might seem inconvenient, but `cheerio` for example is more than 300kB of JavaScript, so being able to use that without sending it to users is a big performance improvement.)

There are a two options here to do what you want:

- Write a `<script>` tag that *includes* all your data fetching and DOM update logic, for example wrapping the default HTML output in a [custom element](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#web-components-with-custom-elements) that re-fetches and re-renders when a data attribute changes.
- Use a [dynamic UI framework](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/) like Preact, Svelte, Vue etc. and use one of Astro’s [hydration directives](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components) like `client:visible` to make it load client-side JavaScript.

Both of these approaches let you send the code to the browser for updating and re-rendering a component, but with different authoring experiences.